# CGI::Fast without tempfiles for upload

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I wish to upload some relatively sensitive data to a server which should not be stored on disk in plaintext - I see it as far too easy to intercept a temporary file and copy the contents, plus there would be the issues of securely deleting the file against restores/journal entries, etc.
I realise I could theoretically do this client-side, but prefer a server-side solution so an unusual browser does not mangle the upload.

Perl CGI::upload_hook() seemed like a perfect solution, with encryption being applied on arrival. Plain CGI is deprecated, but using CGI::Fast, the hook code is never reached, whether I put the call inside or outside the loop.

```perl
use Sys::Syslog;
use CGI::Fast;
sub hook {
    my ( $filename, $buffer, $bytes_read, $data ) = @_;
    syslog('notice',"Hook used!");
}

#CGI::upload_hook(\&hook,'',0); # No good here either
while (my $q = CGI::Fast->new()) {
    CGI::upload_hook(\&hook,'data',0); # No effect
    syslog('notice',"Got a request!");    
    # (Access control code cut)
    print $q->header('text/plain','200 OK');
    print (Dumper($q));
}
```

hook() is never called. CGI::Fast->new() does not accept such hook code in the way that CGI->new() does.

Comment: CGI::Fast is not simply a replacement for CGI.pm. It is an implementation of the CGI.pm API for the FastCGI protocol which happens to still work under the CGI protocol, but it still has all of the same problems as CGI.pm (and actually introduces a few more bugs). If you want to write a CGI (protocol) script using non-discouraged libraries see [my blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/11/modern-perl-cgi.html) for a start.

Comment: I spent a few hours looking into mojilicious, and the other frameworks listed on the 'CGI-alternatives' page,  but I saw a lot about fully-fledged web-apps (not desirable in the least, as it needs to fit in with other bits of the server!) and nothing about file upload hooks, just basic 'move the already-written-to-disk uploaded file here', so I concluded that functionality had been lost. Was I wrong?

Comment: Yes. While everything done in these modern frameworks is a "fully-fledged web app", you don't actually have to write one, just look at any Mojolicious::Lite or Dancer2 example. If you are concerned about how much is going on under the hood, you can use Web::Simple or even Plack directly, but I don't recommend it as it will greatly increase the amount of work you need to do and potential for bugs.

Comment: As for "file upload hooks" specifically, the modern frameworks are of course capable of such but it would not be called that. Though it would take a lot of research to figure out how to properly answer your question using such, I suspect a Plack middleware would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the CGI object is created, it's too late to set the hook. You can use the following:

```
while (1) {
    my $q = CGI::Fast->new(\&hook, 'data', 0)
       or die("Couldn't Accept FCGI request\n");

    syslog('notice',"Got a request!");
    # (Access control code cut)
    print $q->header('text/plain','200 OK');
}
```

Note that this requires CGI::Fast version 2.15 or newer. Earlier versions of CGI::Fast interpreted the upload hook as an initializer and would skip accepting a request.

Comment: CGI::Fast's lack of support has for passing through the constructor hook to CGI has been [fixed](https://github.com/leejo/cgi-fast/issues/19) in forthcoming CGI::Fast 2.15.